# Passing null values along with table keyword is not working in Karate. Is this possible only with scenario outline by adding ! to column headers?

Tags: karate

```
Feature: table keyword demo data driven testing feature

  Scenario: table keyword demo data driven testing scenario
    * table users
      | name    | job    |
      | null    | null   |
    * call read('@user') users

  @ignore @user
  Scenario: create a new user
    Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
    Given request {"name": '#(name)',"job": '#(job)'}
    When method post
    Then status 201
    Then match $ == {name: '#(name)',job: '#(job)',id: #notnull,createdAt: #notnull}
```

I am just checking whether negative data driven testing scenarios can be also covered with table keyword in Karate as that of Scenario Outline and Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose `null` in round-brackets if you really want that column, but with value `null`. This is mentioned in the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#table

```
* table users
  | name    | job    |
  | (null)  | (null) |
```